# Migrating Spring Cloud Connectors to java-cfenv in Cloudfoundry causes TLS failure with Rabbit-MQ service

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit, spring-cloud-dataflow

While upgrading Spring Cloud Services from 2.4.1 to 3.5.5, we are seeing issues with the app not able to connect to Rabbit MQ service in cloud foundry. It throws the following exception:-

`c.r.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler : TLS connection failed: No subject alternative names matching IP address XXX found`

This was never a problem while using version 2.4.1 Spring Auto-reconfiguration and spring cloud connectors were able to create Rabbit MQ connection. Could you please guide me in resolving this issue?

VCAP_VARIABLE sample:

````
{
    "label": "p-rabbitmq",
    "provider": null,
    "plan": "standard",
    "name": "rabbit-service-poc",
    "tags": [
        "rabbitmq",
        "rabbit",
        "messaging",
        "message-queue",
        "amqp",
        "mqtt",
        "stomp"
    ],
    "instance_guid": "VIRTUALHOST",
    "instance_name": "rabbit-service-poc",
    "binding_guid": "USERNAME",
    "binding_name": null,
    "credentials": {
        "dashboard_url": "https://pivotal-rabbitmq.mydomain.com",
        "hostname": "XX.XXX.XX.XX",
        "hostnames": [
            "XX.XXX.XX.XX"
        ],
        "http_api_uri": "https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@pivotal-rabbitmq.mydomain.com/api/",
        "http_api_uris": [
            "https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@pivotal-rabbitmq.mydomain.com/api/"
        ],
        "password": "PASSWORD",
        "protocols": {
            "amqp": {
                "host": "XX.XXX.XX.XX",
                "hosts": [
                    "XX.XXX.XX.XX"
                ],
                "password": "PASSWORD",
                "port": 5672,
                "ssl": false,
                "uri": "amqp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@XX.XXX.XX.XX:5672/VIRTUALHOST",
                "uris": [
                    "amqp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@XX.XXX.XX.XX:5672/VIRTUALHOST"
                ],
                "username": "USERNAME",
                "vhost": "VIRTUALHOST"
            },
            "amqp+ssl": {
                "host": "XX.XXX.XX.XX",
                "hosts": [
                    "XX.XXX.XX.XX"
                ],
                "password": "PASSWORD",
                "port": 5671,
                "ssl": true,
                "uri": "amqps://USERNAME:PASSWORD@XX.XXX.XX.XX:5671/VIRTUALHOST",
                "uris": [
                    "amqps://USERNAME:PASSWORD@XX.XXX.XX.XX:5671/VIRTUALHOST"
                ],
                "username": "USERNAME",
                "vhost": "VIRTUALHOST"
            },
            "management": {
                "host": "XX.XXX.XX.XX",
                "hosts": [
                    "XX.XXX.XX.XX"
                ],
                "password": "PASSWORD",
                "path": "/api/",
                "port": 15672,
                "ssl": false,
                "uri": "http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@XX.XXX.XX.XX:15672/api/",
                "uris": [
                    "http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@XX.XXX.XX.XX:15672/api/"
                ],
                "username": "USERNAME"
            },
            "management+ssl": {
                "host": "XX.XXX.XX.XX",
                "hosts": [
                    "XX.XXX.XX.XX"
                ],
                "password": "PASSWORD",
                "path": "/api/",
                "port": 15672,
                "ssl": false,
                "uri": "http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@XX.XXX.XX.XX:15672/api/",
                "uris": [
                    "http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@XX.XXX.XX.XX:15672/api/"
                ],
                "username": "USERNAME"
            }
        },
        "ssl": true,
        "uri": "amqps://USERNAME:PASSWORD@XX.XXX.XX.XX/VIRTUALHOST",
        "uris": [
            "amqps://USERNAME:PASSWORD@XX.XXX.XX.XX/VIRTUALHOST"
        ],
        "username": "USERNAME",
        "vhost": "VIRTUALHOST"
    },
    "syslog_drain_url": null,
    "volume_mounts": []
}```
````

Comment: Please provide an example of the `VCAP_SERVICES` environment variable that is provided to the application, which should contain the information that both Spring Cloud Connectors and java-cfenv will use to create the connection.

Comment: Hi @ScottFrederick, I have edited my question with sample VCAP variable.

Comment: It appears this might need to be addressed in java-cfenv. If the `uri` and `uris` fields in `VCAP_SERVICES` are empty, then it will create a connection using the `host`, `username`, and `password` fields (https://github.com/pivotal-cf/java-cfenv/blob/main/java-cfenv-boot/src/main/java/io/pivotal/cfenv/spring/boot/AmqpCfEnvProcessor.java#L56-L60). I think it should also look for the `ssl` field in this case. Can you open an issue in https://github.com/pivotal-cf/java-cfenv/issues?

Comment: As a work-around, you might be able to set the `spring.rabbitmq.ssl.enabled` property to `true` in your application configuration.

Comment: @ScottFrederick, I have updated the variable again.. Earlier I had missed to add uri and uris under credentials. The one that has been edited last is the exact VCAP_VARIABLE. It has uri and uris under credentials section. We still see the same error

Comment: Thanks for the update, it makes more sense that the `uri`/`uris` fields had values. I can't see why java-cfenv wouldn't be doing the right thing with the `amqps` scheme in the URI. Looking at your error again, I suspect that the SSL/TLS option is getting set properly but the right certificates are not in the JDK trust store. Has anything else changed with your deployment besides disabling Spring Auto-reconfiguration / Connectors to java-cfenv? Is something like https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack-security-provider used to import certificates needed for the connection?

Comment: Hi @ScottFrederick, Nothing else has changed. DO I have to disable Auto Reconfiguration explicitly?

Comment: I think including java-cfenv in your app automatically disables Spring Auto-Reconfiguration. I'm not sure what else might have changed how the certificates are set up, if I'm right that the problem is with the certificates.

Answer (score 0):

AFAUI, the behavior is managed by [process method of AmqpCfEnvProcessor](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/java-cfenv/blob/main/java-cfenv-boot/src/main/java/io/pivotal/cfenv/spring/boot/AmqpCfEnvProcessor.java#L53-L77) .

In my case (using `cf-env-boot-2.4.3`), I have a custom port for my SSL connection, but it is not being used at application start-up, which also [reported as an issue](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/java-cfenv/issues/220).

Until the issue reported fixed, below workaround worked for me:

**1.** To skip the line `AmqpCfEnvProcessor` sets the `port` value to `5671`, I removed `credentials.uri` from environment variable.

**2.** Doing this also makes `AmqpCfEnvProcessor` to skip some other values. So, I added below values in my application properties.

```
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.port: <MY_CUSTOM_PORT_FOR_SSL_CONNECTION>
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.enabled: true
```

**3.** This way on start-up my application tried to connect an address like below and received exception.

```
10.X.X.X:MY_CUSTOM_PORT_FOR_SSL_CONNECTION:MY_CUSTOM_PORT_FOR_SSL_CONNECTION
```

Since there are 2 port values in the generated address, I removed the port value from `credentials.hostname` to make the generated address contains 1 port value.

Example old value of `credentials.hostname`:

```
10.X.X.X:MY_CUSTOM_PORT_FOR_SSL_CONNECTION
```

Example new value of `credentials.hostname`:

```
10.X.X.X
```

**4.** Finally, my application tried to connect to the right address, but SunCertPathBuilderException is throwed. So, I added below value in my application properties:

```
spring.rabbitmq.ssl.validate-server-certificate: false
```

As a result, my application connected to RabbitMQ successfully.

Some of the steps above may not be required for the problem described in the question, like changing default port values, but overall it may help finding a workaround.